# How to append all the elements at once to create a drop down in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a drop down with three sub menus, so a main dropdown with publishers, a sub menu with authors (which are within that publisher) and a sub menu to authors containing the years they've been published.  So hover over publisher, see authors in that publisher.

It worked fine but i've changed it to improve performance so instead of appending to the DOM each time i've been storing up the values in a variable and then appending to the DOM, however i'm now getting an error

> cannot call method find of null

relating to the line:

```
var author = ulauthors.find('li.author[data-value="' + authorval + '"]');
```

Any ideas how i fix it, i guess because i'm not appending until near the end it can't find the element?

```
var target = $('#listpublishers');
$(info.genres).each(function (i) {
    var genreval = this.genre;
    var catval = this.genreGroup;
    $(this.publishers).each(function (j) {
        var publisherval = this.publisher;
        var ulauthors = null;
        var publisher = target.find('>li.publisher[data-value="' + publisherval + '"]');
        var ulyears = null;
        var publisherstring = '';
        var targetstring = '';
        var ulauthorstring = '';
        var authorstring = '';
        var ulyearstring = '';

        //if publisher does not exist create it else find it
        if (publisher.size() == 0) {
            targetstring += '<li class="publisher" data-value="' + publisherval + '"><a onclick="gotoSubMenu">' + publisherval + '</a>';
            target.append(targetstring)
            publisherstring += '<ul class="sub-menuoos" data-title="publishers></ul>';
            publisher.append(publisherstring)
        } else {
            ulauthors = publisher.find('>ul');
        }
        $(this.authors).each(function () {
            var authorval = this.author + ' (' + genreval + ')';
            var author_val = this.author;
            var author = ulauthors.find('li.author[data-value="' + authorval + '"]');
            if (author.size() == 0) {
                ulauthorstring += '<li class="author" data-value="' + authorval + '"><a onclick="gotoSubMenu">' + authorval + '</a>';
                ulauthors.append(ulauthorstring)
                authorstring += '<ul class="sub-menuoos" data-title="authors></ul>';
                author.append(authorstring);
            } else {
                ulyears = author.find('>ul');
            }
            $(this.publishedYears).each(function () {
                var yearval = this;
                var year = ulyears.find('li.year[data-value="' + yearval + '"]');
                if (year.size() == 0) {
                    var id = ++count;
                    ulyearstring += '<li class="year" data-value="' + yearval + '"><a class="item" id="year"' + id + '"data-year="' + yearval + '" data-publisher="' + publisherval + '" data-author+"' + author_val + '" data-genre="' + genreval + '">' + yearval + '</a>';
                    ulyears.append(year);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

});

Comment: I think its that you start by setting ulauthors as null then publisher size is 0 it never gets reset. and then attempts the second each loop with ulauthors still set as null.

But it's quite hard to tell from just looking at the code

Comment: Have you got some html to show us as well. Or even better, can you give us a http://jsfiddle.net/ to play with?